# UITableViewCell renders wrongly

Tags: uitableview, constraints

My UITableViewCell lines are not working properly. If the label has a long text the wrapping of the text is not made as planned and the cell constraints are also not laying out the cell as should. Line randomly look like these:

[image]

First 3 lines are ok, next two is laid out bad. text should wrap inside.

What is causing this?

The label is constraint on the front and end. The end is constraint to the switch with a larger or equal to 10. Switch is constraint to the right edge. Left and Right constraints are with priority 1000, label to switch with 750.

Comment: Is this from a Storyboard Prototype cell? Or are you doing this via code? Have you set `Number of Lines = 0` on the label?

Comment: Hi, that is storyboard. But I have figured out the problem. A constraint was missing from the switch. It seems even it is a defined control, the width is still needed to make constraints work properly. The problem was that interface builder did not show this as a failure, so I have believed that everything is ok. Once I have typed in a sample text long enough to require wrapping, the missing constraint issue was shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to change any priorities, and you **do not** need to set the width of the switch...

Here is the cell prototype --

- label (yellow background so we can see its frame)

  - constrained Top / Leading / Bottom to content view margins
  - number of lines: 0
- switch

  - constrained Top / Trailing to content view margins
  - Leading to label Trailing `>= 10`

Looks like this in Storyboard:

[image]

and looks like this when running:

[image]

All constraint priorities are at their defaults.

Comment: Hi, hi. Mine was similar but the label trailing was linked to the switch leading. I have solved it differently. Just added the switch width to it and it works now fine. But thanks for the solution.